# Is `p14` an alternative name to arm64 x14 general purpose register?

Tags: ios, assembly, arm64

Source code dumped from apple objc:
[image]

Disassembled code:
[image]

It seems `p14` is an alternative name to arm64 x14 general purpose register. But i could not find any documentation. Could you provide any reference?

Comment: Probably defined as a macro or equ earlier in the code that you did not show.

Comment: @Jester its defined as macro...

Comment: @Jichao So what's the question then?

Comment: @fuz not any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a macro alias for `x14`.  See [arm64-asm.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/arm64-asm.h.auto.html).

This isn't a standard convention and seems to be something specific to the objc source.  It looks like the `p` stands for "pointer", and that when building for something like an ILP32 model with 32-bit pointers, then `p14` gets defined as `w14` instead.